# Geocoder: .nearbys method throwing ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

I'm trying to implement geocoder in my app. I would want to show Nearby places on the page of each place. I keep getting this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    38:            
    39:               %h4 Nearby places
    40:               - @place.nearbys.each do |place|
    41:                 %li
    42:                   = link_to place.name, place
    43:                   (#{place.distance.round(2)} kilometers)

app/views/places/show.html.haml:40:in `_app_views_places_show_html_haml__1604860997730316275_70230188982160'
```

I think this has to do with some places being geocoded and others not. For instance, for this address that I have, in the console, the latitude and longitude values output `nil`, and the `.geocode` method doesn't work on it. However, for other addresses, the latitude and longitude values are automatically generated (as expected). Here is the code I have:
place Model:

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
  geocoded_by :full_address
  after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?

  def full_address
    [address1, address2, city, region].compact.join(", ")
  end

  def address_changed?
    address1_changed? || address2_changed? || city_changed? || region_changed?
  end


end
```

Places controller:

```
def show
  @place = Place.find(params[:id])
end


def create
    @place = Place.new(place_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @place.save
        format.html { redirect_to @place, notice: 'Place was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @place }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @place.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Places show view:

```
          %p= @place.address1
          %p= @place.address2
          %p= @place.city
          %p= @place.region
          %p= @place.phone
          %p= @place.email

          #mapid
           %h4 Nearby places
           - @place.nearbys.each do |place|
             %li
              = link_to place.name, place
              (#{place.distance.round(2)} kilometers)



def place_params
      params.require(:place).permit(:name, :description, :address1, :address2, :city, :region, :phone, :email)
    end
```

As a result I'm only ablate create new places with some addresses while I can with others. How do I prevent this error? I was thinking maybe to have a method that checks if the location latitude and longitude have been generated. If not, then generate them before saving. How do I implement these conditionals?

Answer (score 2):

you can make a simple validation there, something like

```
if @place.nearbys.present?
  - @place.nearbys.each do |place|
    %li
      = link_to place.name, place
      (#{place.distance.round(2)} kilometers)
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Both solutions work. However, would there be a way to force-geocode the locations with nil longitude and latitude values? I am able to find these locations in google maps, but geocoder is unable to geocode them (or automatically assign latitude/longitude values).

Comment: I would suggest to create maybe a rake task  to update lat and lon by the address, so you have all places with those